# Android Listview Cell Overflow Past Extents

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to have a listview cell slide up to partially cover the cell above it. Is there a way to allow content from one cell in a listview to overlap content in another listview cell?

I assume I would use a TranslateAnimation to slide up the top view to reveal the subview, but how to slide over another cell is where I am lost. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but you can retrieve your cell like this:

```
    getListView().getChildAt(index);
```

when index means the position (starting from 0 I guess).
Do the TranslateAnimation and then if you want to make the above cell disappear, just delete it from your list's items array and look for a "refresh list view" method or something alike.

I've never tried it. Try and comment with results.

Good luck!

Comment: I know how to do all the animation. I just need to know if it is possible to show content from within a cell past the extents of the cell.

Comment: What do you mean when you say show content from within a cell pass the extents of the cell? Please be more clear, try giving an example.